# Define download directory for chromedriver selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Everything is in the title!

Is there a way to define the download directory for selenium-chromedriver used with python?

In spite of many research, I haven't found something conclusive...
As a newbie, I've seen many things about "the desired_capabilities" or "the options" for Chromedriver but nothing has resolved my problem... (and I still don't know if it will!)

To explain a little bit more my issue:
I have a lot of url to scan (200 000) and for each url a file to download.
I have to create a table with the url, the information i scrapped on it, AND the name of the file I've just downloaded for each webpage. 
With the volume I have to treat, I've created threads that open multiple instance of chromedriver to speed up the treatment. 
The problem is that every downloaded file arrives in the same default directory and I'm no more able to link a file to an url...
So, the idea is to create a download directory for every thread to manage them one by one.

If someone have the answer to my question in the title OR a workaround to identify the file downloaded and link it with the current url, I will be grateful!

Comment: Generally I would suggest you don't download things using chrome, it's usually a badly thought out test that just downloads everything into a static folder.  Are you doing anything with the downloaded files?  Have a read of this: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/ and then this http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/

Comment: hi
Hello and thanks for your reply.
I actually don't use Selenium to run tests but really to automate massive downloads of data csv file for post treatment.
I've tried to explore the urllib2 way but I met hard difficulties to authenticate on the site... 
(probably because I'm a Sunday-DIY-newbie and Selenium has been the golden-egg goose when I found it!...)

Answer (score 1):

For chromedriver1 create a new profile, and inside that profile set `download.default_directory` to the desired location, and set this profile for chrome using `chrome.profile`. The `selenium-chromedriver` package should have some methods for creating new profiles (at least it does with ruby), as they need some special handling.

Chromedriver2 doesn't support setting the profile. You can set preferences with it. If you want to set the download directory this is how you do it:

```
prefs: { download: { default_directory: "/tmp" } }
```

The ruby selenium-webdriver doesn't support this feature yet, the python variant might do however.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced recently the same issue. Tried a lot of solutions found in the Internet, no one helped. So finally I came to this:

- Launch chrome with empty user-data-dir (in /tmp folder) to let chrome initialize it
- Quit chrome
- Modify Default/Preferences in newly created user-data-dir, add those fields to the root object (just an example):

  "download": {
        "default_directory": "/tmp/tmpX7EADC.downloads",
        "directory_upgrade": true
     }
- Launch chrome again with the same user-data-dir

Now it works just fine.

Another tip: If you don't know file name of file that is going to be downloaded, create snapshot (list of files) of downloads directory, then download the file and find its name by comparin snapshot and current list of files in the downloads directory.

Comment: if you need some sort of Python pseudo code for the problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code....

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: `C#` answer for a `Python` question?